# Calculate ratios of entries in column each month - R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'd like to calculate the ratio of 'none NA' values to 'NA' values in Col1 for each seperate month and input it into a new column (Col1_ratio). Similarly, I would like to calculate the ratio of "s" to "l" for each month and input it into a new column (Col12_ratio). I'd like month to be from month since start, so values above 12 are possible. Is there a way to do this?

Start:

```
set.seed(1)
start = data.frame(
Date = c(sample(seq(as.Date('2010/01/01'), as.Date('2010/04/01'), by="week"), 5), as.Date('2011/01/01')),
Col1 = c("g",NA,NA,"f",NA,NA),
Col2 = c("s","l","s","s","l","s"))
```

Intended output:

```
finish =  data.frame(Month = c(1,2,3,13),
                     Col1_ratio = c(0.33,0,1,0),
                     Col2_ratio = c(0.33,1,1,1 ))
```

I hope I am making sense. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Could you double check your desired output? I don't think it matches the data sampled with the given seed

Comment: @akrun It come from 2011-01 being 13 months after 2010-01 which is month 1. Also I have checked the output and I believe it is alright? Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: can you paste the start data.frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things in your post that do not add up.

1. Using R 4.0, your example data with `seed.seed(1)` does not yield the expected `finish`, and I see no way how it should.
2. You mention the ratio of "s" to "l" for each month as `Col12_ratio`, but the `finish` data.frame only has `Col2_ratio`, which is also not matching up with what I get from the `start` data.frame. I assume this is the correct spelling of `Col12_ratio`.
3. I am not sure you are really looking for the ratio of "s" to "l", which can become Infinite when there is no "l", or for the fraction of "s" per month.

Below is a `data.table` approach that might get you close to what you want.

```r
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
start = data.frame(
    Date = c(sample(seq(as.Date('2010/01/01'), as.Date('2010/04/01'), by="week"), 5), as.Date('2011/01/01')),
    Col1 = c("g",NA,NA,"f",NA,NA),
    Col2 = c("s","l","s","s","l","s"))

# show sorted input
start[order(start$Date),]
#>         Date Col1 Col2
#> 4 2010-01-01    f    s
#> 5 2010-01-08 <NA>    l
#> 2 2010-01-22 <NA>    l
#> 3 2010-02-12 <NA>    s
#> 1 2010-02-26    g    s
#> 6 2011-01-01 <NA>    s

out <- data.table(start, key="Date")[, Date := round(as.IDate(Date), "months")][, 
    .(Col1_ratio=mean(!is.na(Col1)), 
      # Col2_ratio=sum(Col2=="s", na.rm=TRUE)/sum(Col2=="l", na.rm=TRUE)), by=Date]
      Col2_ratio=mean(Col2=="s")), by=Date] # replace with row above if you want s/l ratio
out[, Date:= which(seq(min(Date), max(Date), "month") %in% Date)]
setnames(out, "Date", "Month")[]
#>    Month Col1_ratio Col2_ratio
#> 1:     1  0.3333333  0.3333333
#> 2:     2  0.5000000  1.0000000
#> 3:    13  0.0000000  1.0000000
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am trying to accomplish, thank you! It appears my set.seed does not align with others which is causing the confusion, I will look to rectify this in future.